# how to clear float in this kind of situation (without adding any code to HTML)

Tags: css

Hello I am trying it hard to figure it out how to clear float in this kind of situation ...

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="" width="500" height="688" alt="" />

    <blockquote></blockquote>

    <blockquote></blockquote>


    <cite></cite>


    <h2></h2>

    <p></p>

    <ol>
        <li>
        <img src="" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
        </li>   

        <li>
        <img src="" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
        </li>   

        <li>
        <img src="" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
        </li>   

        <li>
         <img src="" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
        </li>       

        <li>
        <img src="" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
        </li>       

    </ol>       

</div>
```

1- ) I want to float only FIRST image in #content to right but when I apply    #content img{float:right;} , it float all the images even the ones which are in < li > Tag.
How can I float only first image in div and save the rest from floating ?

2 -) I want to position that < Cite > beneath the first float image, how can I clear floats before  ?

PS I don't want to add or change any code in html ,, is it possible to do it from css only ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really really should explain **why** you don't to change the HTML (no access? who wrote the HTML?)

- Like @joffyb said, `#content img` selected **all** images underneath `#content`. Since the other images are also under `#content`, they get selected, too. 
  Use the **immediate-child-selector** instead `#content > imh`.
- As for the second point: You clear floats with `clear:both;` (duh!). In your case `clear:right;` would be sufficient.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. That cite element defines the title of a work (book, song, movie). If you want to caption a picture use `figcaption` in combination with `figure`, e.g.

```
<figure>
    <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/54ac3823e4b0153bb9983ec0/54ace812e4b02240ac8d8758/54aceef8e4b02240ac8e3a26/1420619512639/med_funny-cat.jpg?format=original" width="500" height="688" alt="" />
    <figcaption>Fig.1 - The majestic cat.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Example (just in case):

```css
#content > img {
    float: right;
}
#content cite {
    clear: right;
    float: right;      
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Why am I doing this?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="http://static.squarespace.com/static/54ac3823e4b0153bb9983ec0/54ace812e4b02240ac8d8758/54aceef8e4b02240ac8e3a26/1420619512639/med_funny-cat.jpg?format=original" width="500" height="688" alt="" />

            <blockquote>Important quote</blockquote>

            <blockquote>To be is to do</blockquote>


            <cite>The Bible</cite>


            <h2>Header</h2>

            <p>Some text</p>

            <ol>
                <li>
                    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p2H5YVfZVFw/hqdefault.jpg" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
                </li>   

                <li>
                    <img src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/002/232/bullet_cat.jpg" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
                </li>   

                <li>
                    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p2H5YVfZVFw/hqdefault.jpg" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
                </li>   

                <li>
                    <img src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/002/232/bullet_cat.jpg" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
                </li>       

                <li>
                    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p2H5YVfZVFw/hqdefault.jpg" width="460" height="194" alt="" />
                </li>       
        </ol>       

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much,, It worked and also gave me an clearer picture how floats work .. Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: @imroling Could you be so kind and mark my post as your answer?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the CSS selector you're using is selecting all img tags within the content block.

Try a more specific selector, like immediate children:
`#content > img`